# How can I let the vistors publish a post in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I let the visitors publish a post without registration  in wordpress ?

Any programming modifications suggestions ?

Comment: Let us know the URL so we can block it when it becomes a spam haven.

Comment: @Waseem -- if you're going to let anyone publish on your site, you'll soon find it filled with Viagra ads.

Comment: @tranfosson
I know that , but I need the visitor write a post and I will review it and then I will publish it , the thing that I want the visitor can write a post without registration needed .

Comment: I don't see why registration is such a hassle, but if that isn't an option, why not have them email their post to you?

Answer (score 1):

[TDO Mini Forms](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tdo-mini-forms/) will do what you what you want without too much programming, if any.   Here's part of the description from the plugin page:

> This plugin allows you to add highly customisable forms that work with your Wordpress Theme to your website that allows non-registered users and/or subscribers (also configurable) to submit and edit posts and pages. New posts are kept in "draft" until an admin can publish them (also configurable). Likewise edits can be kept be automatically kept as revisions until an admin approves them. It can optionally use Akismet to check if submissions and contributions are spam. TDO Mini Forms can be used to create "outside-the-box" uses for Wordpress, from Contact Managers, Ad Managers, Collaborate Image Sites, Submit Links, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the standard WordPress settings will allow you to open up the comments. Assuming you're using at least version 2.8, go to Dashboard > Settings > Discussion. Here you'll find the standard options, try this combo ('yes' and 'no' indicate if the boxes are checked):

**Other comment settings:**

*no - Users must be registered and logged in to comment*

**Before a comment appears:**

*yes - An administrator must always approve the comment*

*no - Comment author must have a previously approved comment*

Try this on for size ;-)

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you want visitors to write posts, not comments. My answer above is about comments.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress does have a 'post by email' feature:

> WordPress can be configured to use
>   e-mail to post to a blog. To enable
>   this functionality, you need to:
>
> 1. Create a dedicated e-mail account to be used solely for posting
>      to your blog,
> 2. Configure WordPress to access that account, and
> 3. Configure WordPress to publish messages from the e-mail account
>
> You can blog by e-mail using most
>   standard e-mail software programs or a
>   Weblog Client -- a program
>   specifically designed to send posts
>   via email.

Link to the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Blog_by_Email

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you can use the following plugins: gravity forms (one of the best, but not free) [post from site](http://redradar.net/2010/07/post-from-site-v2-0-1/) and [quick post widget](http://www.famvanakkeren.nl/downloads/quick-post-widget/).
TDO forms is a waste of time, in my opinion: it's very difficult to use and to learn.